# worklight autoplay audio files

Tags: android, jquery, html, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using mobilefirst version 7
Testing on IBM server
Android tablet T110
Android sony c Mobile

target: auto play audio on application launch

followed: [that](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#Media) typically "cordova media apis"

tried jquery mobile code on pagecreate to call playAudio() function from the apis, didn't work either.

html5 autoplay attributes doesn't work too

any suggestions from really experienced people with same cases??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

just called the eventlistener after the autoplay(); function :/

```
var my_media = null;
var mediaTimer = null;

function playAudio(src) {
    // Create Media object from src
    my_media = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);

    // Play audio
    my_media.play();
// Update my_media position every second
if (mediaTimer == null) {
    mediaTimer = setInterval(function() {
        // get my_media position
        my_media.getCurrentPosition(
            // success callback
            function(position) {
                if (position > -1) {
                    setAudioPosition((position) + " sec");
                }
            },
            // error callback
            function(e) {
                console.log("Error getting pos=" + e);
                setAudioPosition("Error: " + e);
            }
        );
    }, 1000);
}
}

// Pause audio
//
function pauseAudio() {
    if (my_media) {
        my_media.pause();
    }
}

// Stop audio
//
function stopAudio() {
    if (my_media) {
        my_media.stop();
    }
    clearInterval(mediaTimer);
    mediaTimer = null;
}

// onSuccess Callback
//
function onSuccess() {
    console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
}

// onError Callback
//
function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}

// Set audio position
//
function setAudioPosition(position) {
    document.getElementById('audio_position').innerHTML = position;
}


document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

//device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
 playAudio("/android_asset/www/default/audio/tail_toddle.mp3");
 playAudio("http://www.tonycuffe.com/mp3/tail%20toddle.mp3");
}
```